# Big query: result is hiding rows where a record is null

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have imported data from Firestore to BigQuery.

I have a field called "hole", which has a planned depth (planned depths can never be null), and an array of measured depths (this can be null). A measured depth has a value, date and person.

If I do a query where I just ask for the planned depths, all the holes are visible in the resulting table:

```
select name,  un_holes.Number as hole_number, un_holes.PlannedDepth.Value as planned_depth
from reporting.reporting_data_staging ,unnest (Holes) as un_holes
where mineName = 'Frasure Creek Mining'
```

This query gives me back all 100 records.

[image: All holes displayed when only using the planned depth]

However, when I add the measured depths, I get only 8 rows back, which are the rows where the measured depth is not null:

```
select name,  un_holes.Number as hole_number, un_holes.PlannedDepth.Value as planned_depth,
         un_measured.Value as measured_depth
from reporting.reporting_data_staging ,
     unnest (Holes) as un_holes, 
     unnest (un_holes.MeasuredDepths) as un_measured
where mineName = 'Frasure Creek Mining'
```

[image: Only 5 holes displayed when I add measured depth to the query]

The result that would like to see the data from the second image, with a blank or null value against the rows were there is no measured data, instead of the rows being cut completely.

I am new to BigQuery and I have done SQL a long time ago. I've searched for similar questions, but I might have made the mistake of not phrasing my search correctly and so have may inadvertently missed out on similar questions, so apologies if I have done this.

Comment: `LEFT/RIGHT OUTER JOIN`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `left join`s to keep rows that have empty arrays:

```
select name,  un_holes.Number as hole_number, un_holes.PlannedDepth.Value as planned_depth,
         un_measured.Value as measured_depth
from reporting.reporting_data_staging left join
     unnest (Holes) as un_holes
     on 1=1 left join
     unnest (un_holes.MeasuredDepths) as un_measured
     on 1=1
where mineName = 'Frasure Creek Mining';
```

When using `unnest()` with `left join`, I think the `on` clauses are unnecessary.  I am not yet progressive enough to leave out `on` clauses for `join`s yet.

Comment: Gordon that worked perfectly! Thank you so much for such a quick and easy resolution to my problem.